# Project specific customization: where to put font-latex-match-reference-keywords?

Tags: auctex, customization

In a project of mine I defined a new LaTeX command `\emphix{...}`, similar to `\emph{...}` and I want its argument to be similarly italicized in my AUCTeX/emacs buffer. To this purpose I defined

```
(setq font-latex-match-italic-command-keywords
  '(("emphix" "{")))
```

This all works when the definition is put in my init file (`.emacs`), but it doesn't work if I put it e.g. in the file `xxxxx.el` which is supposed to contain project specific definition (and, as far as I can understand, is loaded when AUCTeX recognises the style `xxxxx.sty` in my main `.tex` file).

I realised that only when I put the definition in my main init file the variable `font-latex-match-italic-command` is correctly redefined to include it.

Where should I put my definition so that I do not burden my main init file with project specific definitions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the docstring of `font-latex-match-italic-command-keywords`, you see:

> `font-latex-match-italic-command-keywords` is a variable defined in
> ‘font-latex.el’.
>
> Its value is nil
>
> List of keywords and formats for italic-command face.
> Each element has
> to be a list consisting of the name of a macro omitting the leading
> backslash and a format specifier as described in the doc string of
> `font-latex-user-keyword-classes`.
>
> Setting this variable directly does not take effect; restart Emacs.

Last sentence says: This variable must be set before `font-latex.el` is loaded, otherwise it won't work.  This is the reason why setting it in your init file works and not in `xxxxx.el` which will be loaded after `latex.el` and `font-latex.el`.

The usual practice is to write an AUCTeX `xxxxx.el` and use the function `font-latex-add-keywords`:

```lisp
;;; xxxxx.el --- AUCTeX style for `xxxxx.sty'

(TeX-add-style-hook
 "xxxxx"
 (lambda ()

   (TeX-add-symbols
    '("emphix" t))
   
   ;; Fontification
   (when (and (featurep 'font-latex)
              (eq TeX-install-font-lock 'font-latex-setup))
     (font-latex-add-keywords '(("emphix" "{"))
                              'italic-command)))
 TeX-dialect)

;;; xxxxx.el ends here
```